# Shortening a function

Tags: c#

I was tasked with creating a function that receives two numbers and returns True if both are equal and returns False if not. This is what I wrote:

```
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (x == y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
if (x != y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

I was hinted that it is possible to do this with only one line of code. Couldn't figure how to and would like to see how it's possible.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) == int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) ? "True" : "False");`

Comment: See also: [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: This doesn't *return* anything.

Comment: Might be worth using a `int.TryParse` otherwise you'll get an exception if the input is not a int

Comment: @Ric - only if "silent failing" is what you *want*.

Comment: @Ric using `int.TryParse`, I don't see how this could be written in one line

Comment: @Rafalon, depends if the op is using the latest framework, but here: `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int first);`

Comment: Do you want a function to return True/False or to print "True" / "False" ?

Comment: @Ric and how do you compare both inputs in one line?

Comment: @Rafalon - with one of the newer versions of C#: `Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(inputA, out var x) && int.TryParse(inputB, out var y) && x == y);`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a code-review and thus should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Corak oh God...

Comment: return (x == y).ToString();

Comment: added as answer, slightly longer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sice  `Console.WriteLine(true);` outputs `True` you can use

```
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) == int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Comment: OP says requirement is a function that returns true/false - not prints it.

Comment: @PaulF I assume there is a gap between what the OP asks and what he really wants - his current code also doesn't return anything

Comment: True, I was tasked with purely returning not to actually print it.

Comment: @MichaelSH. what's the purpose of the integer convertion? `return Console.ReadLine() == Console.ReadLine();` should do the same

Comment: @fubo unless he wants an `Exception` to be thrown if user writes cr*p

Comment: If I understood your question right, there is no purpose for it, just for practice. Edit - I guess I didn't understand his question. I'm sorry but all of these terms are not really familiar to me yet.

Comment: @fubo: Depends on the requirement. In your case leading zeroes will cause the same number to be treated as different.

Comment: `return Console.ReadLine() == Console.ReadLine();` - fubo. I'd say this is definitely how he wanted me to do this assignment.

Answer (score 3):

using some newer c#7 [Out variables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/):

```
Console.WriteLine(
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int first) &&
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int second) &&
    first == second ? "True" : "False");
```

Comment: "Your [language designers] were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn't stop to think if they should."

Comment: Sorry? this is far better than the previous alternative of declaring an int above the `TryParse` and only using it IF the `TryParse` was successful.

Comment: Is `? "True" : "False"` necessary?

Comment: @Ric - again, only if you *want* silent failing and don't want to treat it as an exception (which has it's place, too). Also, I was joking with that remark; upvoted your answer. -- Rafalon: no -- InBetween: it's more like `bool && bool && bool ? string : string`

Comment: This code is aweful :). If you don't know the correct precedence rules, one would think it does `condition && condition && (condition ? string: string)` (code formatting not helping at all)  but that of course wouldn't compile (classic SO question btw). It actually does `(condition && condition && condition) ? string: string` bu that's completely redundant. `condition && condition && condition` is enough.

Comment: Not really, it follows the OP's logic of writing out if they are equal or not. And thanks for the downvote to whoever that was :)

Comment: @InBetween I wouldn't say awful, as for the ternary operator, OP doesn't have to write out true or false, can be anything, it's just an example

Comment: it was awful with a :). Code formatting is very misleading, I'd actually parenthesize this to make precedence explicit or format it in a more semantic correct way.

Comment: @Ric - oh, sorry, I read that wrong. Yes, of course, the out variables are a godsend!

Comment: so the only problem you have is missing parenthesize? does that make it awful... Everyone has their preferences I suppose. Also worth adding putting this all on one line is quite pointless, it's hardly an optimize and as pointed out can make readability difficult.

Comment: Guys, I'm learning basic C# nothing advanced just yet. These arguments are quite useless from my pov

Comment: Wow, you're taking this too personally, it was a benign comment with no serious criticism behind it. That said, I find your code formatting at first glance misleading as it tends to make you beleive the `?` operator is evaluated before the `&&`. The fact that SO is full of questions asking why this kind of set up is not working or compiling as I expect proves that this is a common, although benign, pitfall.

Comment: @MichaelSH. - agreed. Take it as: there is a lot of fun stuff to discover in the future.

Comment: @InBetween sorry, not taking personally at all! And you're right about SO.

Comment: I'm not saying put it all on one line. The way I'd format this is actually *adding* one more line; I'd enter a new line after `?`.

Comment: @Corak exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) == 
                  int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) ? "True" : "False");
```

This will work for any custom words you need to print, just replace the corresponding strings.

```
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) == 
                  int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Will also work if you always want to print "True" or "False" since the `ToString()` of `boolean` is conveniently capitalized.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose your using a console to try this theory. The parsing and console reading aside.

```
    private bool NumbersEqual(int number1, int number2)
    {
        return number1.Equals(number2);
    }
```

:Edit
Without the method

```
var number1 = 1;
var number2 = 2;

var equal = number1.Equals(number2);

Or truly truly without variable declarations and 1 line
var equal = 1.Equals(2);
```

Comment: He might be asking how to implement and call it on just one line. Of course if you create a method it will be called in a single loc.

Comment: ... or even more truly: `var equal = 1 == 2;`

Comment: @Gonzo345 Right, but even though the lector said "in a function" I'd like to see how you would do it in a method with a single line if possible. (assuming you misspelled loc)

Comment: @MichaelSH. - loc = line of code. -- And it depends on *what exactly* you want to do in one loc. Just comparing if the first argument is the same as the second? Then `bool IsEqual(int a, int b) { return a == b; }` suffices. Do you want to compare if the first input of a user is the same as the second one, you could have something like `bool IsEqual() { return Console.ReadLine() == Console.ReadLine(); }` -- the answers here expected you want to get two user inputs, turn both of them into integers, compare those integers for equality and write something depending on it - *all* in *one* line.